# Vb.net click link by looking for String!

Tags: vb.net, browser, hyperlink

I am working on a vb.net program, I want to click a hyperlink on a page, the source look like this:

```
<a href="user_messages_view.php?id=23112">messages for Today, 2010-10-19 </a>
```

I want to check it everyday too!

I tried to click it with the following methods(Both couldn't click the link!):

```
Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection
    Dim ctrlIdentity As String
     theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
     For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    ctrlIdentity = curElement.GetAttribute("innerText").ToString
     If ctrlIdentity = Today.Date.ToString(Today.Date.ToString("dd")) Then
    curElement.InvokeMember("click")
     End If
     Next
```

and I tried this code too:

```
        If Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Links(i).InnerHtml.Contains(Today.Date.ToString("dd")) Then
    Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Links(i).InvokeMember("Click")
     End If
     Next
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Is this a Forms app or ASP .NET app?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best way to click links in a WebBrowser is using javascript.  Try something like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:function%20x(){document.getElementById('foo').click()}x()")
```

You'll need to rewrite your above code in javascript but that's a piece of cake.  You can test your javascript by copy-pasting it directly into the browser's location bar.  This is also a reliable way to fill out forms.

Caveats:

- Notice how the work that I want to do is wrapped in a function.  This is needed if you want the javascript to do multiple statements.  Wrap in a function and then invoke the function.
- You can't navigate to a URL more than around 500 characters.  (The limit isn't exactly 512 but it's close.)  There's no warning, either, so keep it in mind.
- Make sure you wait until the page is loaded.  The ReadyState = Complete and IsBusy = False.
- Clicking like this doesn't always generate the usual events that you get when you click a link.
- "%20" is hex for space.  I don't recall if this was strictly necessary in my code.  Try it both ways.

Comment: I like the javascript idea, but I want to look for the date string, so it won't click the wrong link. What if I want to click let's say the first 4 link that contains "id:333", can I do that!

Comment: Write a loop in javascript, something like for(var e in document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {if(e.getAttribute("href").test("id:333")) e.click();}  More or less.  Basically you're converting your code from VB.Net to javascript.